# Can I invest RRSP funds in ETFs myself in Canada?

Tags: canada, etf, rrsp, retirement-plan

I've just realized that the funds I have much of my RRSP money in has about 2.25% annual fees. All of the funds available to Desjardins RRSP personal accounts have these high fees.

I've found VFV.TO, an ETF (S&P 500 Index) from Vanguard with < 0.2% fees. I'd like to get at least some of my RRSP money into that if possible. Can I invest RRSP money on my own through an online brokerage account?

Comment: [Yes.](https://www.disnat.com/en/accounts-fees)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: you have to check with Desjardins if you can buy other funds using their broker, but if not you can just open another RRSP account with a better broker who gives you this option. You can open an many RRSPs as you wish.

If you are really unhappy with Desjardins, you can then transfer your money from there to your new broker without being exposed to tax.

> http://www.getsmarteraboutmoney.ca/en/managing-your-money/investing/rrsps-for-retirement/Pages/RRSP-transfers.aspx#.VlOBSHpVKlM